# Integrate testlink with Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking, testlink

How do I create my own issue tracker integration with Testlink tool? I want to integrate Gitlab issues with Testlink.

Thanks.

Comment: I created a gitlab rest Interface having "Redmine rest Interface" as example. Also, I could manage to get Gitlab in the Issuetrackers' drop down list in Testlink UI. 

When I try to create interface, it says 


"PHP Fatal error:  Class 'gitlabrestInterface' not found in /var/www/html/testlink/lib/functions/tlIssueTracker.class.php on line 669, referer: http://localhost/testlink/lib/issuetrackers/issueTrackerView.php"

Comment: New to this, so not able to proceed. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any answers ?
In need of help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the API key, gitlab URL, and project ID in gitlab-rest-api php file under class GitLab. Also, you need to provide this settings inside testlink tool & perform check connection.